# Is MessageBox usable in TestClasses/TestMethods?

Tags: c#

I have created a `TestClass` with multiple `TestMethod`s.  In one of those test methods, I am trying to display information with a popup box using `MessageBox.Show`.  Intellisense does not pick `MessageBox` up here (manually typing also won't resolve the symbol).  I am able to use it elsewhere throughout the project so I was wondering if there is something about test methods that is preventing its use.

Comment: you can add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`. however, its a bad idea as it will block test execution and could cause problems if it you run them on a CI server.

Comment: You can use `Console.WriteLine(...)`

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't even think that would work. MessageBoxes can't work without a message loop being executed. Who's going to run the message loop in test context ?

Comment: Unit Tests are normally not supposed to be interactive as they need to be run by e.g. the build process. In fact, displaying messages to users to confirm that a specific function executed correctly should not really be part of the test and probably mocked using say an "INotificationService". You should simply use Asserts to verify whether a test passes or not.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel AFAIK, MessageBox.Show will create its own message loop, which is why you can use it in a console application.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten You're right.

Comment: I'll go back to `Console.WriteLine`, thanks everyone.  I'm new here so could someone clarify what in the question warranted a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

Since you can use `MessageBox` in the rest of your project, you probably miss the `using System.Windows.Forms`

#### Long answer

I don't think it's a good idea to use a `MessageBox` in a `TestMethod` as it blocks the further test execution. Consider using the [`TestContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.aspx) instead:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{
   // simply declare this property and the test framework will set it
   public TestContext TestContext {get; set;}

   [TestMethod]
   public void MyTestMethod()
   {
      //... your test code
      TestContext.WriteLine("Hey, I got some information for you");
      // more of your test code
   }
}
```

See [`TestContext.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.writeline.aspx) for more information.